# sqlite3_busy_handler callback algorithm

Tags: android, c, ios, sqlite

I have a multi-threaded app running on iphone and android with atleast 6 threads running simultaneously all the time. I see that my sqlite3_busy_handler callback is called very often on android app.

My busy handler *sleeps incrementally* depending on the number of times it is called.

```
sleep((numTries*10) * (numTries + 1));
```

What would be a good retry algorithm here? Should I have a *constant time* sleep in my handler? Should I have a *random time* sleep algorithm? Or is there anything better?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the postDelayed method with a timer, I'm not sure sleeping is the best option.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html